# Which IEqualityComparer is used in a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, iequalitycomparer

Lets say I instantiate a dictionary like this

```
var dictionary  = new Dictionary<MyClass, SomeValue>();
```

And MyClass is my own class that implements an `IEqualityComparer<>`.

Now, when I do operations on the dictionary - such as Add, Contains, TryGetValue etc - does dictionary use the default `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` since I never passed one into the constructor or does it use the IEqualityComparer that MyClass implements?

Thanks

Comment: `EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default` is used. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will use the default equality comparer.

If an object is capable of comparing itself for equality with other objects then it should implement `IEquatable`, not `IEqualityComparer`.  If a type implements `IEquatable` then that will be used as the implementation of `EqualityCOmparer.Default`, followed by the `object.Equals` and `object.GetHashCode` methods otherwise.

An `IEqualityComparer` is designed to compare *other* objects for equality, not itself.

Answer (score 2):

It will use `IEqualityComparer<T>.Default` if you don't specify any equality comparer explicitly.

This default equality comparer will use the methods `Equals` and `GetHashCode` of your class.

Your key class should not implement `IEqualityComparer`, this interface should be implemented when you want to delegate equality comparisons to a different class. When you want the class itself to handle equality comparisons, just override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` (you can also implement `IEquatable<T>` but this is not strictly required).

Comment: If the default equality comparer uses the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods of my class - methods that were overriden when I implemented IEqualityComparer<> - doesn't that mean essentially its not using the default comparer but rather my own?

Comment: Nope. The methods on `IEqualityComparer<T>` have the same names but not the same signatures, so these are not the same methods.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `IEquatable<T>` you can do so without having to create a separate class but you do need to implement [`GetHashCode()`](https://shiftkeysoftware.wordpress.com/2012/09/04/implementing-iequatable-is-not-enough-to-use-a-class-as-a-dictionary-key/).

It will pair up `GetHashCode()` and `bool Equals(T other)` and you don't have to use the archaic `Equals` signature.

```
// tested with Dictionary<T>
public class Animal : IEquatable<Animal>
{
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (species + breed).GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(Animal other)
    {
        return other != null &&
               (
                  this.species == other.species &&
                  this.breed == other.breed &&
                  this.color == other.color                   
               );
    }
}
```