# What comparer should I use for a .NET Dictionary to use the EqualityComparer<T> methods of the Key?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

My `Position` class is derived from the `EqualityComparer<T>` class. I would like the dictionary to use the overridden methods but it is using the methods from `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode`. What comparer should I use for the `Dictionary` to use the `EqualityComparer<T>` methods of the `Position` class?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Position : EqualityComparer<Position>
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(Position left, Position right)
        {
            if (left == null || right == null)
                return false;

            return left.X == right.X && left.Y == right.Y;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode(Position cell)
        {
            if (cell == null)
                return 0;

            return cell.X * 31 + cell.Y;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<Position, int>();
            var position = new Position();
            position.X = 1;
            position.Y = 1;
            dictionary[position] = 1;
            position = new Position();
            position.X = 1;
            position.Y = 1;
            var found = dictionary.TryGetValue(position, out var result);
            Debug.Assert(found);
            Debug.Assert(result == 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "my Position class is derived from the EquailityComparer class." - what exactly do you expect to happen there? Comparer is to compare *some other objects*… likely you mixed it with `Equatable<T>` … Possibly this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853384/which-iequalitycomparer-is-used-in-a-dictionary clarify some...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I expect that Dictionary calls Position.GetHashCode(Position cell) to get the hash code of the Position class and calls Position.Equals(Position left, Position right) to determine if the Position class is the same as in the dictionary or not

Comment: Equality it in is checked by Object.Equals (the no-static one). If you want to change those rules, overwrite that function | Comparers are about finding the relative position of two things. They do that by returning a int. There are two comparers: The default comparer and explicit comparers. | `ICombarable<T>` is the one for the default comparer. However it's function becomes really hard to define, once you got more then 1 field - is X of higher value then Y? | Explicit comparers are stuff like `IComparer<T>`. However in LINQ or with delegates, lambda expressions are also a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is very <strike>awkward</strike> unusual to implement comparer on object itself you simply need to pass an instance of comparer to the `Dictionary` constructor as shown in [EqualityComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8) example.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<Position, int>(new Position());
```

More common approach is to

- use separate class for comparer (if you need multiple variations of comparison) - implement `IEquatable<T>` with typed `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on the type itself (if there is a natural equality like in your case). This is preferable over `object.Equals` approach in case of value types as `Equals(object)` forces boxing of value types.
- just implement `object.Equals` and `object.GetHashCode` as shown in John's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58848349/477420) - this is most straightforward approach for if your type has natural equality and it is a reference type (`class`).

Comment: Got it. I agree, this logic should be separate class.

Comment: @RM I've updated the answer so it likely addresses all concerns you had in comments (including strange "avoid boxing" comment).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative answer: You could just override `Position`'s `GetHashCode` and `Equals` method:

```
class Position
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (other == null || !(other is Position))
        {
            return false;
        }
        var otherPosition = (Position)other;
        return otherPosition.X == this.X && otherPosition.Y == this.Y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.X * 31 + this.Y;
    }
}
```

That way you can simply declare your dictionary like so:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Position, string>();
```

And it will work as you expect.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/QPRQH98770)

Comment: Note that this is exactly what OP *thought* they wanted to avoid - `Equals(object)` requires boxing of a `struct`... but OP has `class Position` - so there is no boxing whatsoever.